# DropzoneJs - Possible to remove "remove link" after upload complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am looking at using [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#) ([actually using the react port of it](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component)) and it has an option called "addRemoveLinks" when true each file gets an individual "remove link".

When you start uploading the file it becomes "cancel upload".

I have set my dropzone to not automatically upload once a file is dragged in, instead when you click an "upload all" button.

Until they click the "upload all" button I want to show the "remove link" but after they click the "upload" button I want to remove that link(ie they can't remove the file once uploaded or cancel it).

Is this possible?

Comment: You should call `function(file) { file._removeLink.remove(); delete file._removeLink; }` on `processing` event (btw I did not try that)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? If I wanted to remove the image from server their I would need to call some function, however I just want to remove it only in memory and once they post it to the server I wan't to disable this feature.

Comment: Now I dont know what you mean)) I thought that you want to remove feature to cancel upload..

Comment: Yes and once the file has been uploaded. If you add a image you can remove as soon as you start to upload you cannot remove and that includes when the image is uploaded. So you can basically think of it as if image is not saved you can remove it. As soon as it's saved you can't remove it.

Comment: And did you tried code that I posted? It should work exactly how you describe..

Comment: Ah, it seems to be doing what I wanted, I had auto processing on so it looked like it was never even shown(file uploaded too fast). I am not sure if processing is the 100% the right place as if the server fails and it comes back as an error I want the user to be able to remove the file if they want. I was thinking of putting your code on "success" but then I have the "cancel" link back again and it does not seem to be separate from the "remove" link

Comment: Then you can put style.display="none" instead of remove() and delete. And on error event you can show it.